# Windows file permission access limited by "Share"

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2012

I cannot understand why I cannot access to a folder with group premission.
Please check its settings:

[image]

This folder (s:\transfer) has full-control permissione for "Domain Admins" group.

[image]

Share has full controll to everyone.

[image]

But if I test the effective access to "Domain Admins" group I cannot access with **Access limited by "Share"**. And I confirm that Domain admins cannot access to this folder!

What I'm missing?

Comment: Does the target folder have any other shares defined on it besides the `transfer` share?

Comment: No, it had a dfs namespace but it was deleted